# Array's lastIndexOf returns -1 when start is undefined

Tags: javascript

in javascript,Array instance has two methods,

```
[].indexOf(searchvalue [,start])
```

and

```
[].lastIndexOf(searchvalue [,start])
```

is behaves strange if the "start" param is undefined:

```
[1,2,3].lastIndexOf(2) // 1
[1,2,3].lastIndexOf(2,undefined) // -1
[1,2,3].indexOf(2,undefined) // 1
```

this happens in chrome and firefox,so what's the theory of the indexOf and lastIndexOf treat "undefined" differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.lastIndexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])
```

> fromIndex The index at which to start searching backwards. Defaults to
>   the array's length, i.e. the whole array will be searched. If the
>   index is greater than or equal to the length of the array, the whole
>   array will be searched. If negative, it is taken as the offset from
>   the end of the array. Note that even when the index is negative, the
>   array is still searched from back to front. If the calculated index is
>   less than 0, -1 is returned, i.e. the array will not be searched.

`[1,2,3].lastIndexOf(2,undefined)` is same as `[1,2,3].lastIndexOf(2, 0)`, so only the first element will be searched.

`[1,2,3].lastIndexOf(2, 0)` will return `-1`.

`[1,2,3].lastIndexOf(1, 0)` will return `0`.

Comment: That's correct,but why when fromIndex is "undfined",it also returns -1

Comment: Citation from the works of a mad Arab scholar, whose name is too famous to be credited?

Comment: @GuanYuxin - It's returning -1 because lastIndexOf hunts *backwards* through the array. If the from parameter is undefined, it starts the search at the first element, which has a value of 1.

Answer (score 2):

`array.indexOf()` begins testing at the specified point and then continues forward until it finds an array element matching the specified value. Therefore, when you're using `[1,2,3].indexOf(2,undefined)`, it's starting at the array element at index 0 (which `undefined` is converted to), and proceeding to test each element:

```
2 == 1 // false
2 == 2 // true, returns index 1
```

`array.lastIndexOf()`, however, begins testing backwards from the specified point. Therefore, when you're using `[1,2,3].lastIndexOf(2,undefined)`, Javascript starts at the array element with an index of 0, then attempts to continue backwards:

```
2 == 1 // false, no more elements to test, return -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a standard implementation of Array lastIndexOf. [Javascript Array lastIndexOf() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_lastindexof.htm)

Note that:

```
var from = Number(arguments[1]);
if (isNaN(from))
{
  from = len - 1;
}
else
{
  from = (from < 0)
       ? Math.ceil(from)
       : Math.floor(from);
  if (from < 0)
    from += len;
  else if (from >= len)
    from = len - 1;
}
```

I initially assumed that `from` equals 0, but actually it is NaN.
  A possible conclusion is that the implementation of mozilla or webkit is not what you want

[Another link-Javascript Array indexOf() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_indexof.htm)

You can see it directly use

```
    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
```